# in search of intepretations and connections for $k$-central binomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, differential-operators, enumerative-combinatorics

Fix a positive integer $k$. Then, the sequences
$$c(n,k)=\frac{k^n}{n!}\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}(1+km)=[x^n]\left(\frac1{1-k^2x}\right)^{1/k}$$
are referred to as "$k$-central binomial coefficients", and [these are always integers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.2028.pdf). For connection with differential Galois groups, [see the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.03227v2.pdf).

> **QUESTIONS.** What do the numbers $c(n,k)$ count? Or, can you provide some interpretation? Can you name some other connections?
>
> Even special cases $k=3, 4, \dots$ (and $n$ arbitrary) would be interesting.

**Example.** $c(n,2)=\binom{2n}n$ enumerate many familiar objects.

Comment: I asked for something similar here but no combinatorial answers so far. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26440/non-arithmetic-proof-of-the-integrality-of-a-rational-expression

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: How did you come across your question? For me, it's because we wrote a paper on these numbers.