# Combinatorial proof of a recurrence for the Catalan numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, catalan-numbers, binomial-coefficients

I would like to ask whether there is a combinatorial proof of the following recurrence relation for Catalan numbers:
$$
C_{n+1}=\frac{4n+2}{n+2} C_n.
$$

Thanks!~

Comment: As no motivation is given, I expect it's a curiosity question. I would suggest to look at Ira Gessel's articles discussing combinatorics of the Catalan numbers (for example, mentioned in the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26336/ but also in the answer of Timothy Chow there).

Comment: I have thought about this (out of curiosity) and I didn't come up with anything so I would be interested in any answers.

Comment: I give up: the newcomers don't care of reading the corresponding wiki pages. So, it's just losing time. For nothing. :-(

Comment: Bruce, how many of the 66 definitions listed in Stanley's "Enumerative combinatorics" did you consider?

Comment: I think giving a combinatorial proof sometimes is a bit tricky. Using not proper interpretations and methods may easily lead to a dead end. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are asking is reported as fourth proof in the wiki article for the formula of the Catalan numbers:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Fourth_proof

Comment: Quite nice proof. I am trying to make a bijection from the polygon interpretation to the noncrossing matching interpretation. My goal is to give a proof in the language of noncrossing matching.

Answer (score 1):

these papers can you help:

http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/catalan.pdf

http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:IPxobgy1BIcJ:www.math.ucsd.edu/~gptesler/184a/catalan_f08-handout.pdf+catalan+number&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiPvWTzNFP0Z5y7CRCrf83opSMRhhCMCNSirJYnBnk_4KnLIIxe6rvj8K2DO39epTp5rZjHszeLloOot62UjlqayX96E9kw-Uw6PJ-eVbE6-rXkH-ZtxBxv6YwJrl9U9-zbJQ5F&sig=AHIEtbTXYSM6J_QnxsOMWpD1_vmFbYe7yg

Comment: Thanks for the first link! I could clearly understand how 'the number of different ways a convex polygon with n + 2 sides can be cut into triangles by connecting vertices with straight lines' problem is solved. 

I just, cant seem to understand the wiki proof!