# An evaluation of the second Chebyshev function

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta-function

Let
$$
\begin{align}
\Lambda (n) & &\text{the Von Mangoldt function,}\\
\psi(x)&:=\sum_{n=1}^{[x]}\Lambda (n)&\text{the econd Chebyshev function,}\\
T(x)&:=\sum_{n=1}^{[x]}\log(n). 
\end{align}
$$
Our goal is to describe $\psi(x)$ in terms of $T(X)$.
Since
$$
T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\psi(x/n),
$$
we can get the following result where $\sum_{n\in I}\Lambda (n)(I\subset [1,x])$ is expressed in terms of $T(x)$

1. Evaluation of $T(x)-2T(x/2)$:
   $$
   \begin{split}T(x)-2T(x/2) &=\psi(x)-\psi(x/2)+\psi(x/3)-\psi(x/4)+\ldots\\
   &=\sum_{n\in I}\Lambda (n)
   \end{split}
   $$
   where $I:=[x/2,x]\cup [x/4,x/3]\cup \cdots$
2. Evaluation of $T(x)+T(x/6)-2T(x/3)-T(x/2)$:
   $$
   \begin{split}
   T(x)+T(x/6)-2T(x/3)-T(x/2) & =\psi(x)-\psi(x/3)+\psi(x/5)-\psi(x/6)+\cdots\\
   & =\sum_{n\in I}\Lambda (n)
   \end{split}$$ where $I:=[x/3,x]\cup [x/6,x/5]\cup \cdots$
3. Evaluation of $T(x)-T(x/2)-T(x/3)+T(x/30)$:
   $$
   \begin{split}
   T(x)-T(x/2)-T(x/3)+T(x/30) &=\psi(x)-\psi(x/6)+\psi(x/7)-\psi(x/10)+\psi(x/11)-\psi(x/12)\\
   &\quad +\psi(x/13)-\psi(x/15)+\psi(x/17)-\psi(x/18)+\psi(x/19)-\psi(x/20)\\
   &\quad\quad +\psi(x/23)-\psi(x/24)+\psi(x/29)-\psi(x/30)+\ldots\\
   &=\sum_{n\in I}\Lambda (n)
   \end{split}
   $$ where $I:=[x/6,x]\cup [x/10,x/7]\cup \ldots$

**My questions are**:

1. Are there any mechanism to find these combination?
2. Can we extend the above subset $I$?
3. In particular, can we extend $I$ so that $[x/n,x]\subset I$ for some $n\ge7$

Comment: See the discussion here for answers to all these questions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26342/chebyshevs-approach-to-the-distribution-of-primes

Comment: See also pages 47-48 and 69 in Montgomery and Vaughan's book.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Answer (score 1):

For

$$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \Lambda(n)$$

and

$$T(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \log(n)$$

one has

$$\psi(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \mu(n)\, T\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)$$

and

$$T(x)=\sum _{n=1}^x \psi \left(\frac{x}{n}\right).$$